# c# - case statement for logical operators

Tags: c#

I am getting "cannot implicitly convert string to char" error. I am trying the following code, how should I specify the cast in the case statement for the <= operator. any help/direction is appreciated. Thanks!

```
char test1;
    switch(test1)
    {
       case '+':
        //do something
        break;

      case '-' : case '*' : case '<=' :
       //method1
       break

    method 1:

    private void method1(char test2)

    {
      if(test2 == '+' || test2 == '*' || test2.ToString() == "<=")
       {
         token.Add(test2.ToString());
       }
    }
```

---

ok, I have a method1 like this:

```
private void Method1(char test2)
{
  if(test2 == '+' || test2 == '-' || test2 == '/' || test2 == '*')
    {
       //code
       tokens.add(test2);
    }

char test1;
        switch(test1)
        {
           case '+': case '-' : case '*': case '/':
            Method1(test1);
            break;
```

I am trying to get the tokens if there is an expression like (a+b)*(a-b). tokens is a list of string here. but, what I am also trying to do here is also check for logical operators if they exist in the expression...ex: (a+b)<=5, in this case, I want to check if the next token is <=, if so add it to the list of tokens, the goal is to have one method to handle all the operators(+,-, *,/,<=,>=, ==, !=) and call it in the switch case statement.

Comment: Fix your code. This code wouldn't compile the way it is.

Comment: If you have one char, how can that ever be two chars? The check does not make sense in the first place. What are you really after?

Comment: By the way, how do you expect `test2.ToString()` to be equal to "<="? How can one character be equal to two characters?

Comment: In your switch statement you have a case with '<=', there are two characters, which is invalid (it is not a valid "char").

Comment: You probably need to work with `string` everywhere, instead of `char`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an actionDictionary to do that instead of switch case statement:

```
private void Test(string operant)
{
    Dictionary<string, Action> actionMap = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
    // map operant to action methods
    actionMap.Add("+", new Action(AddToken));
    actionMap.Add("-", new Action(AddToken));
    actionMap.Add("*", new Action(AddToken));
    actionMap.Add(">=", () =>
    {
        // anynomous method
        token.Add(">=");
    });
    actionMap.Add("/", new Action(Divide));
    actionMap.Add("<=", new Action(LessThanOrEqual));

    // list keep continue here


    foreach (string key in actionMap.Keys)
    {
        if (key == operant)
        {
            actionMap[key]();
        }

    }
}

private void AddToken()
{
}

private void Divide()
{
}

private void LessThanOrEqual()
{
}

// .. and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying use a String (kind of) in a switch statement (`'<='`).

I'd use a map from a string to a function that "do[es] something". I've found trying to force use a switch causes more problems than it solves.